# Should object be created with minimal scope?

Tags: java

This one may seem trivial to some, but I'm trying to adopt good habits right from the start...

Should objects always be created with minimal scope?

In the example below, `corner1` only gets used inside the loop. Is it best practice to then create (declare) it inside the loop?

i.e. do this

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        DoubleVector corner1 = new DoubleVector();

        // code where corner1 gets used
    }
```

and not

```
    DoubleVector corner1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        corner1 = new DoubleVector();

        // code where corner1 gets used
    }
```

Of course, if I need `corner1` later on, then I guess I have to go with the second option.

Comment: *Should objects always be created with minimal scope?* Yes :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a case of creating *objects* with minimal scope, but declaring *variables* with minimal scope. It's worth differentiating between the two.

But yes, it's generally best practice to limit the scope of your variables as narrowly as sanely possible - and declare them only when you need to, as well. The smaller the area of code in which your variable appears, the easier it is to understand how it's used and where it came from.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is best practice to declare it in the loop.  In this case the reason is mainly for code cleanliness.  It's easier to read if the declaration is close to the initialization, and it better documents how the variable is used.

Of course, if the object can be *shared* across all iterations of the loop, it might be a valid optimization to put the declaration *and* initialization before the loop.

Comment: Shouldn't have any impact on GC. Either it's referred to (e.g. by the variable) or it isn't, but that variable won't hold multiple references simultaneously if it has a larger scope. Variable scope doesn't matter (except for the JIT, which may remove the variable and hence the references a bit earlier - but that's actually more useful with larger scopes), it only matters what's reachable at the point at which collection happens.

Comment: @delnan: It shouldn't have any impact on a *good* GC.  But a naive implementation would have an easier time with a reference going out of scope than computing that it won't be used anymore.

Comment: Not even reference counting does more work in either case (since the refcount changes on assignment just like on variable creation/removal). All other GCs run only from time to time and only care about what's referenced in that very instant, not when it may go out of scope. Plus, even if some weird GC tried to predict lifetime of references, it wouldn't matter if that particular reference is removed due to a variable going out of scope or due to an assignment. Also, JVMs generally feature really clever GCs. Long story short, I don't see any reason to even mention GC here, it's just confusing.

Comment: @delnan: If reference counting happens on assignment or variables going out of scope, the reference count for the last value of `corner1` would not go down to zero until the end of the *method* if it were declared outside of the loop.  If it were declared inside of the loop, the reference count would go down to zero at the end of the loop.  There can be code between the end of the loop and the end of the method.  That's all I was trying to say.  Anyway, I will remove that comment since I wasn't trying to say something strongly with it, just that a more naive GC would benefit from it.

Comment: @delnan: reading your comments I think you missed that I only ever said it might have an effect in garbage collecting the **last** instance of `corner1`, not any of them before then.  And what I meant to say was that it gives better *hints* to the runtime/compiler, not that it would make a difference in practice.

Comment: Yes, I did indeed miss that part. It never crossed my mind that such a delay for a single instance might be interesting, as it's 1 of N (read: potentially ten thousand) objects and the overall behaviour would be dominated by what happens to the N-1 other objects. My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is good practice to minimise the scope of your variables.  It reduces clutter, and reduces the chance of accidentally using the wrong thing at the wrong time.

Answer (score 1):

it is always good practise to limit the scope of variable and object.
Not only for code cleanes but because it give chanches to the garbage collector to reuse clean the hip (if speaking about object and not variable as in this case).

furthermore having large visibility of variable is more error prone while writing code.