# Why do "f" and "g" ASCII characters turn negative in this code?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*************** CAESAR CYPHER *****************

  -Take a charater array input
  -Loop through 26 character shifts
  -Print all possibilities
  
************************************************/

void Brute_Force(char *message)// Character array pointer
{
    char *i;// Copy message for iteration: Stop at '/0'
    int j;// Iterate through the alphabet
    char t;//Temp variable for current letter
    
    for(j = 0; j < 26; j++)
    {   
        printf("\n----------Shift %i----------\n", j);//Aesthetics

        for(i = message; *i != '\0'; i++)
        {
            //Multiple of 26 to start at original message
            unsigned char t = ((*i + j)%26) + 104;
            
            // Only loop 97 to 122. ASCII 'a'-'z'
            if(t > 122){t = t - 26;}
            printf("%c", t);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char mess[26] = "ynkooejcpdanqxeykjrbdofgkq";
    Brute_Force(mess);
    return 0;
}
```

Before changing `t` to an `unsigned char` instead of a regular `char`, every time 'f'(102) or 'g'(103) would come up, it would output `t = -127/-128` instead of `127/128`. I'm just wondering what would have caused it to change to negative. It was only for 'f' and 'g', every other letter was correct.

a sample output would be:

```
ynkooejcpdanqxeykjrbdo��kq
```

Comment: `char` is a signed type on many systems, so when it exceeds 127, you have overflow and hence undefined behavior.  Commonly this results in wrapping around to negative values in the usual way of two's complement arithmetic.  Applying the `%` operator to a negative value gives a negative result.

Comment: As a `char`, the expression `((*i + j)%26) + 104` would be negative if it exceeds 127. I suspect this expression did that when the character was `f` or `g`. In fact, it happens any time the expression `(*i + h)%26` exceeds 23. Incidentally, the first `char t` serves no purpose in the code version you show currently.

Comment: Why are you adding 104?

Comment: Don't use the magic number `122`.  If you want to compare to `z`, then do it directly: `if( t > 'z') ...`

Comment: as said, the first `char t` is unused. And you should move `i` and `j` declaration to inside the `for` loop. Variables should be declared in the smallest scope as possible

Comment: @smac89 It's a multiple of 26. I did it so the output started on the original message. I've learned that the better way to do it is `((*i - 97 +  j)%26) + 97`

Comment: @lurker Thanks, I I forgot to take that out...

Comment: @phuclv Is there a specific reason for this, or is it just a general rule?

Comment: @PhyllaciousArmadillo it's general rule in almost every language [Declaring variables inside loops, good practice or bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7959573/995714), [Declare variables at top of function or in separate scopes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3773396/995714), [Minimalizing variable's scope in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59578451/995714), [“Variables should be given the smallest scope”. Really?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42847980/995714), [Should object be created with minimal scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7485877/995714)

Comment: [Optimal declaration of variables with regards to scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4075246/995714). And it appears in pretty much every C or C++ coding standard: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/DCL19-C.+Minimize+the+scope+of+variables+and+functions, https://www.appentra.com/knowledge/checks/pwr002/